# Angular - How to change dropzone color when drag a image

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with angular and developed an image input.
In this input I developed a dropzone that serves to drag the files.

How can I change the dropzone background when dragging a file there? This lets me know if the drop is active to get my file there or not.

Can anyone help me?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="drop" >
      <div class="cont">
        <div class="browse" >
            Upload 
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="abc">            
      </div>
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple accept="image/*">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the drag and drop events from angular:

```
<div (dragenter)="dropzoneHovered = true" (dragleave)="dropzoneHovered = false">
```

then apply the CSS class on the element of you liking:

```
[class.drag-active]="dropzoneHovered"
```

For example:

```
.drag-active {
  background: red; 
}
```

You can see it in action in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-and-drop-htfrhy?file=src/app/app.component.html)